# What is Forbidden constructor, use a literal or simple function call instead error by gulp tslint?

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, tslint

I am working on angular 2 application using ag-grid plugin and gulp as build tool -

```
   #225 function onPageSizeChanged(pageSize) {
   #226     this.pageSize = new Number(pageSize);
        createNewDatasource();
    }
```

I am getting below error message for above code -

> [gulp-tslint] error app/app.component.ts[226, 21]: Forbidden constructor, use a literal or simple function call instead

Please let me know if this information is not sufficient, I will provide further details. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
this.pageSize = pageSize;
```

What's the intention of using `new Number(pageSize);` anyway?

See also https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/noConstructRule.ts#L26

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Gunter. Maybe that can be done directly, I just want to know what use Number class/constructor have.

Comment: The lint contains more information. See the link in my updated answer.